# Full-Minidump does not allow me to debug the native memory part

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, debugging, unmanaged

We are running a service in a Linux container on a Kubernetes cluster. The task is to get out core dumps for debugging in case of failure. That works fine but even though everything seems to be set up correctly I can not debug native with the core dump.

Setting up the dump went fine, a volume claim and some environment variables later and I can get my core dump.

The dumping is set up with two variables

```
COMPlus_DbgEnableMiniDump=1
COMPlus_DbgMiniDumpType=4
```

as specified here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/collect-dumps-crash

When the crash happens on the managed C# side, everything is great, I have my relevant pdb and dll files and can jump straight to the source of error.

But if the crash happens in a module in unmanaged/native memory, nothing. I am opening the dump as specified here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-dump-files

But I do not get the options "Debug with Native". Visual Studio also says the file is a "Managed Linux Core Dump".

The debug console reports "[createdump] Writing full dump to file /tmp/coredump.3352" so it seems everything is set up correctly. Aparently it is not.

What do I have to do to make the dump debuggable with native? A different setup or a different way of opening?